# How to change all routes with language codes

Tags: routing

I need to dublicate all existing routes with several language codes:

```
/2020/03/11/Hello-world
/en/2020/03/11/Hello-world
/de/2020/03/11/Hello-world

/Hello-world-page
/en/Hello-world-page
/de/Hello-world-page

/...
/en/...
/de/...
```

Then I need to pre-handle all routes to check prefix exists and get as slug, then let related handlers do thier jobs.. I searched it many many times but never lucky to solve..

How to accomplish that? Thank you!

Comment: Note that doing this would result in duplicated content which carries an SEO penalty. By default WP will redirect to the canonical page, and put the canonical URL in a meta tag to try and avoid this. Why would you want to duplicate all the URLs?

Comment: @TomJNowell Well, for language and localization codes.. /en/us/Hello-world for example.. Maybe no need to do it with routing, it would be great that get route before wp proccess, seperate codes, then let wp does it jobs.

Comment: If you want to support URLs for multiple languages, that's the question you need to be asking. Focus on finding solutions for that specific problem, rather than the solution you've thought of, and you'll have an easier time.

Answer (score 0):

```
add_filter('do_parse_request',function($state){

    // Here you can change every request URL by $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']

    return $state;

},1,1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to make the website Multilingual, so in order to achieve that, take a look at the [Article on wordpress.org](https://wordpress.org/support/article/multilingual-wordpress/) which says,

> WordPress does not support a bilingual or multilingual blog out-of-the-box. There are however Plugins developed by the WordPress community which will allow you to create a multilingual blog easily.
>   The free [WPGlobus](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wpglobus/), [Polylang](https://wordpress.org/plugins/polylang/), [qTranslate-X](https://wordpress.org/plugins/qtranslate-x/), [xili-language](https://wordpress.org/plugins/xili-language/) or Sublanguage plugins are installable on standalone WordPress sites. For multisite WordPress (one website per language), you can try [Multisite Language Switcher](https://wordpress.org/plugins/multisite-language-switcher/), Zanto or [Multilingual Press](https://wordpress.org/plugins/multilingual-press/) or purchase [WPML](https://wpml.org/).

You will get your routes having language code with some plugin mentioned above.